# How to draw multiple polylines using Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a list of latitude and longitude in database and I want to draw more polyline on google maps.
For example:

```
var i, j;
var polyline1 = new Array(latt.length);

str = new Array(latt.length);
for (var k = 0; k < latt.length; k++) {
    i = latt[k].split(',');
    j = longg[k].split(',');
    str[k] = 'new GLatLng(' + i[0] + ',' + j[0] + ')' + ',';
    for (var count = 1; count < i.length; count++) {
        str[k] += 'new GLatLng(' + i[count] + ',' + j[count] + ')' + ',';
    }
    str[k] = str[k] + 'new GLatLng(' + i[0] + ',' + j[0] + ')';

    polyline1[k] = new GPolyline([str[k]], "#ff0000", 6);

    map.addOverlay(polyline1[k]);

    map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
    map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
}
```

but I'm getting error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand the error - I can't see an `a` anywhere - but you're almost certainly using [GPolyline](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GPolyline) wrong. It wants an array of objects, not a single-element array of a string of JavaScript:

```
var polyline1 = new Array(latt.length);

str = new Array(latt.length);
for (var k = 0; k < latt.length; k++) {
    var i = latt[k].split(',');
    var j = longg[k].split(',');

    var latlngs = [];
    for (var count = 0; count < i.length; count++) {
        latlngs.push(new GLatLng(parseFloat(i[count]), parseFloat(j[count])));
    }
    polyline1[k] = new GPolyline(latlngs, "#ff0000", 6);

    map.addOverlay(polyline1[k]);
}

map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
```

I don't know if the `parseFloat`s are actually necessary. You probably want to move the control adds outside the loop too.

Comment: hi, Actualy i am new to google maps , I have list of latitude and longitude and i want to draw polyline . So can u please provide me solution with example ..

Comment: Doesn't that now work? I think that's about right. [Here's a very basic example](http://rupey.net/runs/2006TwoCastlesRoute.html) I did a long time ago, just dumping data from my GPS watch onto a page in the simplest way I could. I'm sure there are better ways to do this, though - I don't know a lot about the API.